# Angular range slider's watch does not trigger if directive is inside a template

Tags: angularjs, slider

I'm using the [Angular Range Slider](https://github.com/danielcrisp/angular-rangeslider) plugin. The `$watch` triggers for my `$scope.start` variable as I slide my left anchor, aka start value, *only* if it's outside of any templates. However, the `$watch` function does *not* trigger if the directive is inside of a template.

Example screenshot:
[image]

Live: http://codepen.io/ianhd/pen/VvxPre?editors=101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `model-min="$parent.startInsideOfTemplate"`

As you are putting it inside a template, it belongs to its parent's scope